# Rails 7 - Devise overriding Registrations controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I am using `Devise` gem in my Ruby on Rails application. I want to have a functionality where a logged in user can create a new user. I know Devise default behavior and I am being routed to the root route when I try accessing the `new_user_registration_path` after logging in.

Therefore, I am trying to override Devise Registration controller to allow a logged in user create a new user. Below is the code what I have written.

I have created a new file named `registrations_controller.rb` in the Controllers folder. Below is the code.

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:new, :create]

  # Customize the create action to allow new user creation
  def create
    if current_user.admin? # Check if the current user is an admin or has necessary privileges
      super
    else
      # Handle unauthorized user attempting to create a new user
      flash[:alert] = "You are not authorized to create a new user."
      redirect_to root_path
    end
  end

end
```

Below is the `Routes.rb` code:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'tools/create'
  get 'tools/update'
  get 'home/homepage'
  get 'home/lightwave_users'
  post 'home/import_users'
  get 'home/operations'
  get 'home/tools'
  post 'home/update_tool_record'
  get 'home/show_operation'
  delete 'home/delete_operation/:id', to: 'home#delete_operation', as: :home_delete_operation
  delete 'home/delete_user/:id', to: 'home#delete_user', as: :home_delete_user
  delete 'home/delete_all_created_operations'

  devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: 'registrations' }


  # Defines the root path route ("/")
  root "home#homepage"

  # Below route is required for logout functionality.
  devise_scope :user do
    get 'users/sign_out' => "devise/sessions#destroy"
  end
end
```

For some reason Devise is not intercepting this overriden controller and it still routes me to root route when I try accessing `new_user_registrations_path` after loggin in.

Comment: Shoehorning more functionality into `Devise::RegistrationsController` is not a good way to go about this. It adds a lot of complexity and violates the Single Responibility Principle - handling user sign up and creating other users is not the same thing. If you want Admins to be able to create users you can either use [Devise::Invitable](https://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable) or just create a normal CRUD controller (UsersController).

Comment: Thank you @max for your response. I understand your suggestions but just I am curious to understand what wrong I am doing in this code as far as just Rails is concerned. I am seeing this message in console `Filter chain halted as :require_no_authentication rendered or redirected`. I know this message is appearing because I am trying to create a new user while I am logged in as a user. But what wrong am I doing in overriding the create method.

Comment: Well the reason this doesn't work is that the controller action in the superclass is not intended to accessed by signed in users and there is a callback preventing this. Looking at this problem "as far as just Rails is concerned" is kind of a waste of time because the problem is not in your controller action. Its rather that you're trying to use a very advanced peice of modular code for a use that it was never intended. I know you're not going to listen to me but don't waste more time on this idea. Just do it the right way and spend some more time trying to learn the Rails crud conventions.

Comment: Probably you even don't need registrations controller at all since you want to prohibit sign up by standard flow of Devise